# Brakeman does not like rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, rubygems, brakeman

I have this method inside a model with this code inside. It calls a gem and returns either the object I want or a 404 resource not found. if I do a method on a 404 then I need to rescue it as shown below. If I just use rescue the linter fails. If I do this brakeman fails.

```
find_object
  return_object = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key + '/variableInsideObject') do
    GemClient.find(id).variableInsideObject
    rescue HttpServices::ResourceNotFoundError
    raise ApplicationController::ExternalServiceError,
        "variable inside object not found for id: #{id}"
  end
end
```

How can I rescue this error without failing the linter and brakeman.

Comment: What is the error that the linter/brakeman give you? This doesn't look like how one would normally rescue errors in rails.

Comment: That's the thing. Brakeman just has a parse error on a random line. It doesn't apply to my code. when I do just
    rescue raise {stuff}
then the linter doesn't allow a blanket rescue without raising an error but brakeman is fine.

Comment: What is `find_object`? Is there an `def` missing? Is it only missing in this question or is that the reason for the parsing error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imo this is a more Ruby-esque implementation of this code:

```
def find_object
  return_object = begin
    Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key + '/variableInsideObject') do
      GemClient.find(id).variableInsideObject
    end
  rescue HttpServices::ResourceNotFoundError => e
    Rails.logger.error(e)
    raise ApplicationController::ExternalServiceError,
      "variable inside object not found for id: #{id}"
  end
end
```

Of course, it's hard to say without knowing what the linter or brakeman are complaining about exactly.... but this should be better. You don't of course need to use begin end blocks, but sometimes linters/community finds it is neater...

Comment: IMO you cannot reach `Rails.logger.error(e)` after raising an exception...

Comment: This worked except for e. I just did not print it in the logger. Why would brakeman not like my original implementation?

Comment: If you make that change I can approve it :)

Comment: @Taariq Hard to tell when you do not tell us the exacty message brakeman gave.

Comment: It's not useful. I can add it, but your solution minus the logger fixed the issue. Brakeman breaks on a random line. If I remove that it just breaks elsewhere.
I understand though. I just thought Stuart would know since the answer worked.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Brakeman parse error essentially points right to the issue, not a random line. The issue is you are using rescue inside a block without `begin`, which is a relatively new syntax ([introduced in Ruby 2.5.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/)). RubyParser (used by Brakeman and maybe your "linter") doesn't have a release that supports the new syntax yet, although it's [fixed in master](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser/pull/264).